# After uploading an attachment by Paperclip, how to view the attachment online?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have uploaded an attachment by using Paperclip, which can be any format from .txt to .cpp, and I want to add a function, which is to view this attachment online. But I　don't know where to start? Can anyone give me some help? Thank you~

Comment: I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= link_to image_tag(@result.image.url,:size => "150x180" ) %>
```

try this formate in show.
@result is your => variable where your all data field is in
and image is the field name.. Try it

Comment: Thanks, but what the .url is supposed to be here? string ?

Comment: I tried but I think I didn't get your point. Sorry for that cause I'm new in ROR.Suppose the attachment variable is @attachment, so will it be something like @attachment."/attachment/1/read"?

Comment: <%= link_to image_tag(@attachment.image.url,:size => "150x180" ) %>in your show.  In your model add this  include Mongoid::Paperclip
  has_mongoid_attached_file :image    In your form try this <div class="form-inputs">
     <%= f.input :image, :as => :file ,:label=>"Upload Document" %>
  </div>

Answer (score 0):

In Rails, there should be a `Show` page, a `Edit` page. After you upload an attachment, which is supposed to be done on `Edit` page, redirect to the `Show` page, and display the attachment file, no matter it's .txt or .cpp

Comment: I didn't follow the Show and Edit rule, I use restful but I add somehing myself. The content of the attachment is supposed to be shown on the Read page of view Attachment. I tried to display the attachment file, but it gave me a string of the information of the attachment.

Comment: when a controller is generated, by default, there are show, new, create, edit, update methods. these are the default RESTFul methods. You are useing restful, but don't know these methods?

Comment: But how to open .doc files?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<%=link_to  'Show Attachment',@object.file_attribute.url(:original,false), :title=>"Show" %>
```

Comment: it works, but only for the formats that the browser supports. I still cannot open a .doc file. Could you offer any help?